# Python application and Apache with wgsi

Tags: python, apache2

I have an application related to html web page and working fine using the command line:

```
export FLASK_APP=db_website_management.py
[export FLASK_ENV=development]
flask run
```

Now I want that the wgsi call the app in order to use it with Apache, but I don't really know how to do that. I've tried with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import logging

sys.path.append('/var/www/dbwebsite')
sys.path.append('/var/www/dbwebsite/dbwebsite')


import db_website_management as application
```

but it gives me an error:

```
[Fri Feb 19 10:50:40.914786 2021] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 222722] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Feb 19 10:50:40.916966 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 222722] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Feb 19 10:50:40.916991 2021] [core:notice] [pid 222722] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd'
[Fri Feb 19 10:50:44.980311 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29766] INFO:root:Connection to database FGVD_hg19 created.
[Fri Feb 19 10:50:44.986516 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29766] [client 157.27.74.238:52848] mod_wsgi (pid=29766): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/dbwebsite/dbwebsite.wsgi'.
[Fri Feb 19 10:50:44.986571 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29766] [client 157.27.74.238:52848] TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.
```

The folder is structured:

```
dbwebsite.wsgi
dbwebsite/
--- db_website_management.py
--- other script
```

Thanks a lot.
Denise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the official documentation. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/mod_wsgi/#creating-a-wsgi-file

Without knowing how your application is called I cannot tell you the exact correct line, yet it should be something like

```
from db_website_management import app as application
```

(assuming that your app is called `app`) instead of

```
import db_website_management as application
```

Further you will have to move the `dbwebsite.wsgi` to the `dbwebsite` folder, or create a python module out of the `dbwebsite` folder, by creating one of those `__init__.py` files inside of it and then adjusting the import path accordingly to `from dbwebsite.db_website_management import app as application`